# Update One Duplicate Column in a table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I'm trying to update duplicate username records in a table.  Here is the update I've come up with, but this updates all duplicate records.  How could I just update one?

```
update xxx_users set username = CONCAT(username,"dup") where exists(
 SELECT username, COUNT(username) FROM xxx_users GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(username) > 1);
```

I appreciate any help that could be provided.  Thanks!

Comment: your xxx_users have a primary key?  .. an autoincrement id??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your xxx_users table have a primary key based on an autoincremented id you could try:

```
     update xxx_users u
     inner join  (
        select min(id)  id
        from xxx_users 
        group by username
        having count(*)>1

     ) t ON t.id  = u.id
     set username = CONCAT(username,"dup")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm getting a #1054 - Unknown column 't.id' in 'on clause' using your suggestion.

Comment: And yes, the table has an autoincrement ID column.

Comment: You needed an "as id" after the select min(id) line.